# How to use regex expression in Katalon Studio?

Tags: regex, katalon-studio

I have a regex expression which checks for the valid date and timezone format but when I tried to use it in Katalon, I get unexpected errors about using the slases:

```
^\d\d([-/])\d\d\1\d{4} \d\d:\d\d [AP]M ET$
```

Here's an example of the regex that seems to be working in here: https://regex101.com/r/nZC9PB/1

Comment: It is not clear what the exact issue you got. Please also share the relevant docs, else, please  file a support request in the tool support. SO is a site for programming issues, not 3rd party software issues.

Answer (score 2):

The regex expression by user should work well in some languages / platform, but in order to make it accurate to Katalon, we should use escaped character '' before '/' in '[-/]'. So that Katalon Studio can understand the regex expression correctly.

The correct regex expression should be:

`^\d\d([-\/])\d\d\1\d{4} \d\d:\d\d [AP]M ET$`

Answer (score 1):

For doublequoted string in groovy you have to escape every `\` and `$` --> `\\` and `\$`

But there is a slashy string in groovy where you need to escape only slash symbol `/` --> `\/`

https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string

```
def re = /^\d\d([-\/])\d\d\1\d{4} \d\d:\d\d [AP]M ET$/
assert "06-01-2023 11:59 PM ET" =~ re

"Ok"
```